# Adding up particular part of String from a Value input

Tags: javascript, substring

I'm now working on a piece of code where I need to add the first 3 characters on the string, and then compare them to the last 2 characters to make sure they match.

> e.g: ID 12306 is Valid, as 1+2+3 = 6, and 0+6 = 6.

I did find a topic previously on here (back in 2012) regarding a similar issue, however the code example used 2 static number variables, and when I tried to implement the same method using my HTML input value, it seems to do nothing.

```js
var custId = document.getElementById("custid").value;

function validateId(custid) {
  var custId2 = custId;
  var custId3 = custId;

  custId2 = custId2.substring(0, 2);
  custId3 = custId3.substring(3, 5);

  custid = custid.split('');
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < custid.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(custid[i], 10);
  }

  return sum;

  if (add(custId2) != add(custId3)) {
    output = "ID error. The first three digits must sum to the value ' +
             'of digits 4 and 5. e.g. 12306 is a valid value";
    output = custId2 + "<br />" + custId3;
    addToOutput();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: you mixed up `custid` and `custId`. It could be the reason

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Coz you have a `return` statement in between and you are looping on `custid` completely. So please specify the exact problem

Comment: you have a return statement in the middle of the function. the function is missing a closing brace. your code doesn't show how you call the function or how it is attached to the input element. you haven't shown what the "add" function is. your `custid` vs `custId` casing is inconsistant

Comment: Sorry about that, been operating on about 2 hours sleep, so hasn't been the best night (I blame Jetlag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your method has numerous issues as stated in the comments (incorrect casing, multiple returns, substring index), I have provided a solution you can use to your liking.

```
var validateId = function(custId) {
  var custId2 = custId.substring(0, 3).split('');
  var custId3 = custId.substring(3,5).split('');

  var sum2 = 0; 
  var sum3 = 0; 

  custId2.forEach((e) => {
    sum2 += parseInt(e);
  })

  custId3.forEach((e) => {
    sum3 += parseInt(e);
  })

  if(sum2 !== sum3) {
    console.log("ID error. The first three digits must sum to the value of digits 4 and 5. e.g. 12306 is a valid value")
  } else {
    console.log("Success");
  }
}

validateId("12306");
```

**Example - http://plnkr.co/edit/vtrU8Hs4Bv6FJS1qFnKn?p=preview**

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get it working with the following code:

```
function processData(){
    var custId = document.getElementById("custid").value;
    var custName = document.getElementById("custname").value;
    var ticketType = document.getElementById("tickettype").value;
    var ticketQty = document.getElementById("qty").value;
    var delType = document.getElementById("delivtype").value;
    validateId(custId);

function validateId(custId){
    if(!custId){
        output = "Customer ID cannot be blank";
        addToOutput();
        return false;}

    if(custId.length != 5){
        output = "Customer ID must be 5 digits in length";
        addToOutput();
        return false;}

    if(isNaN(custId)){
        output = "Customer ID must be numeric";
        addToOutput();
        return false;}

    var custId2 = custId;
    var custId3 = custId;

    custId2 = custId.substring(0,3);
    custId3 = custId.substring(3,5);

    custId = custId.split('');
    var sum = 0;
    var sum2 = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < custId2.length; i++){
        sum += parseInt(custId2[i],10);
    }

    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < custId3.length; i2++){
        sum2 += parseInt(custId3[i2],10);
    }

    if(sum !== sum2){
        output = "ID error. The first three digits must sum to the value of digits 4 and 5. e.g. 12306 is a valid value";
        addToOutput();
        return false;}

    output = "Customer ID Valid!"
    addToOutput();
    return true;
}
```